# Encoding extended naturals in SBV

Tags: haskell, z3, smt, sbv

I'm experimenting with the following way of encoding extended naturals in SMT-LIB (I define a datatype analogous to `Maybe Integer`):

```
; extended integers -- if first field is true, then the value is infinity
(declare-datatypes () ((IntX (mk-int-x (is-infty Bool) (not-infty Int)))))

; addition
(define-fun plus ((x IntX) (y IntX)) IntX
  (ite (or (is-infty x) (is-infty y))
           (mk-int-x true 0)
           (mk-int-x false (+ (not-infty x) (not-infty y)))))

(declare-fun x () IntX)
(assert (= x (plus x (mk-int-x false 1))))
; x = x+1 when x |-> infty
(get-model)
(exit)
```

How would I go about to encode this in SBV? I tried the following, but that just crashed SBV. Also I somehow doubt that this would do what I want, but I'm not familiar enough with how SBV works.

```
!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script
  --resolver nightly-2018-11-23
  --package sbv
  --package syb
-}

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Generics
import Data.SBV

data IntX = IntX (Maybe Integer) deriving (Eq, Ord, Data, Read, Show, SymWord, HasKind)

pretty :: IntX -> String
pretty = \case
  IntX Nothing -> "∞"
  IntX n -> show n

instance Num IntX where
  (+) (IntX x) (IntX y) = IntX $ (+) <$> x <*> y
  (*) (IntX x) (IntX y) = IntX $ (*) <$> x <*> y
  fromInteger = IntX . Just

ex1 = sat $ do
  x :: SBV IntX <- free "x"
  return $ x .== x + 1

main :: IO ()
main = print =<< ex1
```

---

```
~/temp ✘ ./sbv.hs
sbv.hs: SBV.SMT.SMTLib2.cvtExp.sh: impossible happened; can't translate: s0 + s1
CallStack (from HasCallStack):

  error, called at ./Data/SBV/SMT/SMTLib2.hs:681:13 in sbv-7.12-9AiNAYtrUhB8YA6mr6BTn4:Data.SBV.SMT.SMTLib2
```

Comment: The functions `abs`, `negate` and `signum` has not implemented for `class Num`. Otherwise, the code seems no problem.

Comment: Hm, I've implemented the missing methods, but it crashes all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that your code is mixing Haskell's concrete `Maybe` type and trying to treat it as a symbolic object. But you're on the right track with how you implemented that in SMT-Lib2: You essentially need to write the corresponding code in SBV.

I'd start with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns  #-}

import Data.SBV
import Data.SBV.Control
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
```

This is just boilerplate; and you don't need the `Data.SBV.Control` import unless you want to use the query mode, but it does come in handy as we shall see.

The first thing to do is to encode your `IntX` type symbolically; just like you did in SMTLib:

```
data SIntX = SIntX { isInf :: SBool
                   , xVal  :: SInteger
                   }
                   deriving (Generic, Mergeable)

instance Show SIntX where
  show (SIntX inf val) = case (unliteral inf, unliteral val) of
                           (Just True,  _)      -> "oo"
                           (Just False, Just n) -> show n
                           _                    -> "<symbolic>"
```

Nothing above should be surprising, except perhaps the deriving of `Generic` and `Mergeable`. It simply enables SBV to be able to use `ite` on your extended naturals. Also note how the `Show` instance is careful in distinguishing concrete and symbolic values by using `unliteral`.

Next, we add a few convenience functions, again nothing surprising:

```
inf :: SIntX
inf = SIntX { isInf = true, xVal = 0 }

nat :: SInteger -> SIntX
nat v = SIntX { isInf = false, xVal = v }

liftU :: (SInteger -> SInteger) -> SIntX -> SIntX
liftU op a = ite (isInf a) inf (nat (op (xVal a)))

liftB :: (SInteger -> SInteger -> SInteger) -> SIntX -> SIntX -> SIntX
liftB op a b = ite (isInf a ||| isInf b) inf (nat (xVal a `op` xVal b))
```

Now we can make `IntX` a number:

```
instance Num SIntX where
  (+)         = liftB (+)
  (*)         = liftB (*)
  negate      = liftU negate
  abs         = liftU abs
  signum      = liftU signum
  fromInteger = nat . literal
```

(Note that the semantics of this means `oo - oo = oo`, which is at best questionable. But that's besides the point. You might have to explicitly define `-` and deal with that as you wish. Similar comments apply for `signum`.)

Since you want to test for equality, we also have to define the symbolic version of that:

```
instance EqSymbolic SIntX where
  a .== b = ite (isInf a &&& isInf b) true
          $ ite (isInf a ||| isInf b) false
          $ xVal a .== xVal b
```

Similarly, if you want to compare, you'll have to define an [`OrdSymbolic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-7.12/docs/Data-SBV.html#t:OrdSymbolic) instance; but the idea remains the same.

We need a way to create symbolic extended naturals. The following function does it nicely:

```
freeSIntX :: String -> Symbolic SIntX
freeSIntX nm = do i <- sBool    $ nm ++ "_isInf"
                  v <- sInteger $ nm ++ "_xVal"
                  return $ SIntX { isInf = i, xVal = v }
```

Strictly speaking, you don't need to name the variables. (i.e., the `nm` parameter isn't needed.) But I find it helpful to always name my variables for obvious reasons.

Now, we can code your example:

```
ex1 :: IO SatResult
ex1 = sat $ do x <- freeSIntX "x"
               return $ x .== x+1
```

When I run this, I get:

```
*Main> ex1
Satisfiable. Model:
  x_isInf = True :: Bool
  x_xVal  =    0 :: Integer
```

Which is what you were looking for, I believe.

When you're dealing with larger programs, it's beneficial to be able to extract `IntX` values more directly and program further with them. This is when the query mode comes in handy. First, a helper:

```
data IntX = IntX (Maybe Integer) deriving Show

queryX :: SIntX -> Query IntX
queryX (SIntX {isInf, xVal}) = do
          b <- getValue isInf
          v <- getValue xVal
          return $ IntX $ if b then Nothing
                               else Just v
```

Now we can code:

```
ex2 :: IO ()
ex2 = runSMT $ do x <- freeSIntX "x"
                  constrain $ x .== x+1

                  query $ do cs <- checkSat
                             case cs of
                               Unk   -> error "Solver said Unknown!"
                               Unsat -> error "Solver said Unsatisfiable!"
                               Sat   -> do v <- queryX x
                                           io $ print v
```

And we get:

```
*Main> ex2
IntX Nothing
```

I hope this helps. I've put all this code in a gist: https://gist.github.com/LeventErkok/facfd067b813028390c89803b3a0e887

Comment: Extremely helpful answer. Thank you for going into so much detail.

Comment: PS: in my case I am dealing with constraints over the semiring (Nat U {oo}, +, *, 0, 1), so I don't want to have to think about subtraction/inverses. Therefore, I think I will just leave out the irrelevant definitions and ignore that GHC is yelling at me... I also add the constraint `v .>= 0` to the definition of `freeSIntX` (or more appropriately `freeSNatX`).

Comment: You can replace the "irrelevant" definitions with `error "shouldn't be called!"` just to be safe. And yes; adding `constrain $ v .>= 0` to `freeSNatX` is a nice trick. One thing to worry about is that your modeling domain has "junk" in it, in the domain theoretic sense: A single infinity is modeled by (infinitely) many distinct elements. This can cause trouble in certain cases, but there are ways to deal with that should it be a problem.

Comment: If I understand your point right, I thought of this too, so I've decided to use `xVal = -1` in the infinity case: `constrain $ ite i (v .== -1) (v .>= 0)`. Of course this means that the boolean (`isInf`) constraints are sort of superfluous, because I could just denote infinity using the integer's sign bit. Not sure if that is a good idea though.

Comment: I know that originally I had called my type `IntX`, but really I want just `Nat`s, so using the sign bit of the `SInteger` seems fair.

I tried encoding infinity as `(-1)`, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/buggymcbugfix/1afea2d466e5dc21655a76037accccdd

Note the special case for 0 in my definition for `(*)`, which I need for my model (resource analysis: not using a computation that consumes arbitrary resources uses no resources).

Comment: I was thinking more along `allSat` like situations, where you want to find all satisfying assignments. Since the model contains junk, the SMT solver would return "different" results which are essentially the same for you. (The way to deal with that is to assert the negation of the equivalence class in a query.) But looks like that's not an issue for you, and perhaps the `>= -1` constraint sufficient as it eliminates the junk and lack of subtraction avoids that space. So long as it works, all is good!